# Creating a variable with a random number

Tags: javascript, jquery, variables

I have two variables: img1 and img2. I have a random number generator that generates either 1 or 2. I need to make a variable based off of that, so it'll be img1 or img2.

Here's the code I have so far:

```
var $img1 = "<img src=\"slides/leo.jpg\" /><footer>King Leo of TWiT TV</footer>";
var $img2 = "<img src=\"slides/leo-inverted.jpg\" /><footer>VT TiWT fo oeL gniK</footer>";
var $rand = Math.floor(Math.random()*2) + parseFloat(1);
var $slide = $slide.add($rand);
$("#slideshow").html($slide);
```

It works if I put either `$img1` or `$img2` as the `.html()` on the last line, but I can't figure out how to make it pick randomly.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You should probably avoid naming variables with a `$` in front unless they are jQuery objects. That may confuse other scripters. Using an array will solve your problem too:

```
var imgs = [
    "<img src=\"slides/leo.jpg\" /><footer>King Leo of TWiT TV</footer>",
    "<img src=\"slides/leo-inverted.jpg\" /><footer>VT TiWT fo oeL gniK</footer>"
];
$("#slideshow").html(imgs[Math.floor(Math.random()*imgs.length)]);
```

Comment: @Rev It works: http://jsfiddle.net/yWcXe/. What is in $slide before hand though, what are you using it for?

Comment: Ah I think I just forgot to clear a line from my old code. It does work, thank you very much :) I'm using it in place of a slideshow, as a static image that changes randomly.